# Loading image with Glide causes exception

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to get a drawable from a url with Glide but it keeps failing.

I'm using Glide version 4.12.0 which is the latest: `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'`

I've already tried using RequestListener but it kept failing, therefore I am looking for an alternative.

imageUrl = https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/podsync-dev.appspot.com/o/commentImages%2FAB5D35BB-E925-486A-A280-81358636D8EB?alt=media&token=daf6f99c-323a-4cfc-af97-3354d9f8e4e9

### Here's my code:

```
comment.imageURL?.takeIf { loadImage }?.let { imageUrl ->
    Glide.with(context).load(comment.imageURL).into(object : CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
        override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
            // code
        }
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable,
                                     transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {

            // code
        }
        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            // code
        }
    })
}
```

### Here's the exception I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/galdahan/podsync/Models/Comment$Companion$transform$5$1;
        at com.galdahan.podsync.Models.Comment$Companion.transform(Comment.kt:71)
        at com.galdahan.podsync.Models.Comment$Companion.transform$default(Comment.kt:47)
        at com.galdahan.podsync.FIREBASE_API.Post_CommnentsApi$observeComments$1.onDataChange(Post_CommnentsApi.kt:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.galdahan.podsync.Models.Comment$Companion$transform$5$1" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.galdahan.podsync/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes6.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~u26Hv32StBK7WzdCxOOa-A==/com.galdahan.podsync-gxbX5HkcbxEI2A_Cnrev2A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~u26Hv32StBK7WzdCxOOa-A==/com.galdahan.podsync-gxbX5HkcbxEI2A_Cnrev2A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.galdahan.podsync.Models.Comment$Companion.transform(Comment.kt:71) 
        at com.galdahan.podsync.Models.Comment$Companion.transform$default(Comment.kt:47) 
        at com.galdahan.podsync.FIREBASE_API.Post_CommnentsApi$observeComments$1.onDataChange(Post_CommnentsApi.kt:75) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:179) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You did not tell how the url looks like.

Comment: @blackapps Right, I've updated the question with the link, thanks.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.galdahan.podsync.Models.Comment$Companion$transform$5$1" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.galdahan.podsync/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes6.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~u26Hv32StBK7WzdCxOOa-A==/com.galdahan.podsync-gxbX5HkcbxEI2A_Cnrev2A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~u26Hv32StBK7WzdCxOOa-A==/com.galdahan.podsync-gxbX5HkcbxEI2A_Cnrev2A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]  ` What does that have to do with Glide?. Try to download the file without Glide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace, here are some few things that can be observed.

- You are loading your data from firebase.
- You have some form of implementation to map the data into models in podsync/Models/ when the firebase notifies you of changes.

Here's what you can do to single out your problem:

- Comment out your code(glide implementation) to load the image
- Comment out your mappings of objects from firebase to your models
- Log your data from firebase to be sure of the structure/format that they are being loaded in.

At this point, your app should not be crashing. Proceed;

- Carefully examine the Comment object from firebase and establish where the differences come from with your model(datatypes, number of children/properties, e.t.c) of comment or whichever model you are using to map it.

If you are listening to data changes inside `onDataChange`, you can use a try/catch to get the value from the snapshot and log it before conversion(as I had mentioned earlier).

Once you are sure of the fields in the expected object, update your model accordingly, then access the `imageUrl` property and pass it over to glide.

In summary, glide is not the cause of this crash, instead, it's how your data is being mapped to your local models.

Comment: You were right, I've updated the question's code, please have a look at the first line. The cause of the crash was because I used `let` and `takeIf` at the first line, I replaced them with a simple if statement and it's fixed. But I don't understand why ... doesn't Glide know how to work with Kotlin's functions? maybe I need to add a special dependency to make Glide work with Kotlin?

Comment: That's good. I'd recommend you get to learn the Kotlin inbuilt functions contained in the standard libraries - they are handy, however, if misused , they can tilt things unexpectedly. All the best!